# What does polling a variable mean?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

What does polling a variable mean?? While using semaphores for synchronization does busy waiting indicate checking for a variable continuously or polling of variable. What is the difference between the two(if there is any). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does polling a variable mean??

Typically the word "polling" isn't used on a variable *per se*, but on some resource -- you poll a socket to see if it can be read.

In general though, polling means asking, in a loop, "Ready?" "No" "Ready?" "No" "Ready?" "Yes"

> While using semaphores for synchronization does busy waiting indicate checking for a variable continuously or polling of variable. What is the difference between the two(if there is any)

Since the terminology doesn't really apply (a Google search for 'polling variable' yielded nothing interesting) I have to say that yes, they mean the same thing.

In a busy-loop, the CPU is continuously checking a variable ("busy-waiting") to see if it meets some criteria.  For `wait`ing on a semaphore, this criteria is whether the value is greater than zero.